# grunt async task timeout

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, yeoman

I've an async task but it timeouts in 5 seconds and grunt moves on to the next task:

```
grunt.registerTask("something", '', function(target){

    var done = this.async();

    function checkStatus ()
    {
        console.log('test');
        if(someCondition)
            done();
    }
    setInterval(checkStatus, 500);
});
```

I see 9 'test' messages in the terminal and then it just moves to the next task, without further waiting to the 'done'.
I haven't found any limits or time restrictions in the code of grunt.
Why does that happen ?

`grunt 0.4.8rc1`

Comment: btw, I'm spawning a child process in one task and I want grunt to hold on running as long as the child process is working. This task is supposed to watch the process and report `done` when the child process spawned in previous task is done.

Comment: Have you tried to use 'exec' instead of 'spawn'?

Comment: Ye, but it has little to do with the issue, as the code in the question itself spawns nothing.

Comment: Could you post a simplified use case that triggers the behavior?  When I run your task as written above with a variable 'somCondition' declared outside the task and set to false, the task runs forever.  There must be something else that is causing grunt to move on.

grunt-cli v0.1.7
grunt v0.4.1